# Trying to access response from Activity

Tags: java, android

Im calling an activity which should get me a value

Call:

```
Intent customDescription = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CustomDescription.class);
customDescription.putExtra("DESCRIPCIONES",descriptionsArray);
                               startActivityForResult(customDescription,DESCRIPTION_SELECT_REQUEST_CODE);
```

On Activity Result:

```
if (requestCode == DESCRIPTION_SELECT_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                CustomDescription=data.getStringExtra("descripcion");
            }
```

CustomDescription Definition:

public static String CustomDescription;

Since startActivityForResult is asynchronous I'm never getting a value in CustomDescription. How can I get it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement [`onActivityResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)). In your calling activity you then call `setResult([your code]);` and finish the activity. The code you set in `setResult` is the parameter of onActivityResult. You can optionally also add an Intent as data to `setResult`.

But note that `startActivityForResult` deprecated. You should instead do it [that way](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)